# using Nasm and gcc on windows (MinGW) for osdev

Tags: c, windows, assembly, gcc, osdev

I am currently creating a simple kernel and I just jumped to using C with the GCC(MinGW) compiler on windows. but the way I am using C with assembly is kind of problematic here is what I am doing :

```
:: First I am assembling the assembly files down to a flat binary   
nasm -f bin Assembly/asm.asm -o asm.bin


:: doing the same thing for the C files
gcc -c C/c.c     
objcopy -O binary -j .text c.o c.bin



:: combing the all binaries by adding them together In the desired order
COPY /B asm.bin + c.bin + asm1.asm ..... os.bin
```

it is kind of working, but it is also tedious working that way, first I have to break the code into segments (because I am adding each binary file on top of the other), I have to calculate the addresses manually by looking at the raw binary files, and I can't call functions from other files .

what should I do ?  What is the best way to combine C and Nasm assembly on windows for OSdev ? I am guessing I should use a some sort of a linker or something.

Note that I want also to be able to call assembly functions inside c and use C functions inside assembly .

Comment: Yes, link first (don't use flat binary for the asm) and then do the `objcopy`.

Comment: Maybe a bit off-topic, but since you are using `gcc`, then why not use `gas` for assembly?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have developed a strong familiarity with NASM syntax and directives since I first began working with assembly language. So, NASM has become my go-to choice and the assembler with which I am most comfortable with.

Comment: @Jester when I assemble down to an object file certain directives won't work for example, the org directive doesn't work, the [bits 32] directive also produces an error

Comment: Right, you don't use `org`. If you care you can set base address using linker. The `bits` should not produce an error, but you should already be targeting 32 bits if you want to link with C code so you don't need it. The 16 bit boot sector should be assembled separately (you don't want to link C code there).

Comment: @Jester can you please go into more details on what should I do, I mean the exact commands ? I looked online but nothing worked .